# Combining numbers and names collections

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have 2 List collections. One contains numbers, the other names. There are twice as many numbers as names(always). I want to take the first name from the collection and the first two numbers from the other collection then put them together in a 3rd user collection of (VentriloUser). Then the second name needs to be matched with the 3rd and 4th numbers and so on.

I was thinking something with a for or foreach loop, but I can't wrap my head around it right now.

```
public class VentriloUser
    {
        public VentriloUser(string name, int seconds, int ping)
        {
            Name = name; Seconds = seconds; Ping = ping;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Ping { get; set; }
        public int Seconds { get; set; }
    }

public class Ventrilo
    {
        public Ventrilo(string statusurl)
        {
            StatusURL = statusurl;
        }

        public string StatusURL { get; set; }

        public string HTML { get; set; }

        public List<VentriloUser> Users { get; set; }

        private Regex findNumbers = new Regex("\\<td width=\"10%\" bgcolor=\"#\\w{6}\"\\>\\<font color=\"#000000\">\\<div style=\"overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis\"\\>-?\\d+\\<");
        private Regex findNames = new Regex("\\<td width=\"20%\" bgcolor=\"#\\w{6}\"\\>\\<font color=\"#000000\">\\<div style=\"overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis\"\\>\\b\\w+\\<");

        private WebClient wClient = new WebClient();

        public void DownloadHTML()
        {
            HTML = wClient.DownloadString(StatusURL);
        }

        public List<int> GetNumbers()
        {
            var rawnumbers = findNumbers.Matches(HTML);
            var numbers = new List<int>();

            foreach (var rawnumber in rawnumbers)
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(rawnumber.ToString(), "\\>\\-?\\d+\\<");

                string number = Regex.Replace(match.ToString(), "\\<|\\>", "");

                numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(number));
            }

            return numbers;
        }
        public List<string> GetNames()
        {
            var rawnames = findNames.Matches(HTML);
            var names = new List<string>();

            foreach (var rawname in rawnames)
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(rawname.ToString(), "\\>\\w+<");

                string name = Regex.Replace(match.ToString(), "\\<|\\>", "");

                names.Add(name);
            }

            return names;
        }

        public List<VentriloUser> GenerateUsers()
        {
            var numbers = GetNumbers();
            var names = GetNames();

            var users = new List<VentriloUser>();
        }


    }
```

I am a hobbyist, but hope to pursue a career one day. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var users = names.Select((name,idx) => new VentriloUser(name, numbers[idx*2], numbers[idx*2+1]))
                 .ToList();
```

Using loops:

```
var users = new List<VentriloUser>();
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
{
    var name = names[i];
    int j = i * 2;
    if (j >= numbers.Count - 1)
        break; // to be safe...
    users.Add(new VentriloUser(name, numbers[j], numbers[j + 1]));
}
```

Comment: I added the constructor to VentriloUser. I am not to familiar with LINQ ( I would rather use it though ). I believe your example only shows adding 1 number with 1 name. I may be mistaken.

Comment: Ah I got it... sorry, I thought it was 2 user with the same name, but different Ping. It's one user and 2 numbers (i.e. ping and seconds) instead... I'm going to modify the code...